# Is there a way to shut down, restart or log off without seeing the popup?

Tags: macos

I would like to know if there is a way to delete the popup shown when you are trying to shut down, restart or log off your Mac with version OS X 10.9 - What I want is that when I click on one of these buttons, the computer makes that action without asking for a confirmation and the countdown of 1 minute.

I know you can use Alt+Shut down/Restart/Log off but I would like to know if there is a direct way to deactivate that popup via Terminal or something else.

Comment: Are you talking about the menu items in the Apple menu?

Comment: @NReilingh yes that is right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few methods to shutdown without confirmation (this will not remove the confirmation from the original method):

1. In Terminal: `shutdown -h now`, but this **force** quits all applications
2. Make an Applescript and save it as 'Application,' save it somewhere easily accessible, **but not prone to accidental clicks**:

   > ```
   > on run
   >   do shell script "shutdown -h now"
   > end run
   > ```
3. The shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>-<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>-<kbd>⏏ Eject</kbd>
4. Clicking shutdown with <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> / <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> held down (as you said)
5. If using [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com), you can summon the Alfred window and start typing "Shut down" or "Restart" and then pressing Enter. No Power Pack needed, no force quits, no dialog and no countdown.

You could also try following [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17261128#17261128) method by WZZZ, but I haven't checked if it works. It reduces the time to auto-quit apps, so do:

```
defaults write org.x.X11 wm_auto_quit_timeout -int x
```

Comment: That default seems very unlikely X11 is a windowing system not used by most Apps

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but the only way to have the Apple menu items not prompt for confirmation (and without the use of the option modifier) would involve editing the system's interface files to substitute the "now" items that display with the option key for the ones that display normally.

My approach would be to expand on item #3 of shub's answer:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> - Shutdown
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> - Restart
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - Log Out

Also some elaboration on the AppleScript approach:

```
tell application "System Events"
    shut down           -- or 'log out' or 'restart' or 'sleep'
end tell
```

This won't ask for confirmation but also won't force-quit everything.