# How can I stop applications from preventing restarts?

Tags: macos, restart, reboot

I have some applications that routinely prevent restarts from happening correctly (most often *iTerm2* and *Slack*, though others participate as well). When I request a *Restart*, these applications will present an "Are you sure?" dialog and halt the restart process.

This annoying most of the time, but especially so when I've requested system updates to install overnight and I instead waste the first several minutes of my day after clicking "Yes I'm sure" and then allowing the reboot to proceed.

Is it possible to tell OSX to **always** reboot when requested and never stop for user input?

Comment: What is stopping you from logging out after you say restart tonight?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129646/is-there-a-way-to-shut-down-restart-or-log-off-without-seeing-the-popup?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist to not save any work, open terminal and run `sudo shutdown -r now`

You could force the updates as well before issuing the restart with `softwareupdate -ai` and never see an “Are you sure?” or “Save this data?” dialog since the shutdown command sends SIGKILL which kills as opposed to asking nicely for programs to exit.

Back up your files, the filesystem will be safe but your data in specific files won’t necessarily be safe.